# How does fold distinguish x from xs in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, fold

```
sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum' xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs
```

There is no pattern like `x:xs`. `xs` is a list. In the lambda function, how does the expression `acc + x` knows that `x` is the element in `xs`?

Comment: What do you mean? `x` and `xs` are simply variables. You could have written `xs:x` in which case `xs` is an element, and `x` the list, or `a:z`...

Comment: Easy: `sum'` doesn't have a pattern like `x:xs`, but `foldl` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is no pattern like `x:xs`. xs is a list. In the lambda function, how does the expression `acc + x` knows that `x` is the element in `xs`?

In Haskell - like in many programming languages - the **name of a variable does not matter**. For Haskell it does not matter if you write `xs`, or `x`, or `acc`, or use another identifier. What matters here is actually the position of the arguments.

The [**`foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) is a function that takes as input a function with type `a -> b -> a`, followed by an object of type `a`, followed by a list of elements of type `b`, and returns an object of type `a`.

Semantically the *second* parameter of the function, will be the elements of the list. If you thus wrote `\x acc -> x + acc`, `acc` would be the eleemnts of the list, and `x` the accumulator.

The reason why this binds is because `foldl` is implemented like:

```
foldl f z [] = z
foldl f z (x:xs) = foldl f (f z x) xs
```

It thus is defined itself in Haskell, and thus binds the function to `f`, the initial element to `z`, and performs recursion to eventually obtain the result by making a recurslive call where we take the tail of the list, and use `(f z x)` as new initial value until the list is exhausted.

You can write the sum more elegant as:

```
sum' :: Num n => [n] -> n
sum' = foldl (+) 0
```

so here there are no *explicit* variables in use at all.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't "know" anything like that - there's no magic going on here.

The definition of foldl is equivalent to:

```
foldl f acc (x:xs) = foldl f (f acc x) xs
foldl _ acc [] = acc
```

So going through a simple example using your `sum'` function:

We start with

```
sum' [1,2,3]
```

substituting the definition of `sum'` we get

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 [1,2,3]
```

substituting the definition of `foldl` (first case):

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((\acc x -> acc + x) 0 1) [2,3]
```

evaluation the function application of your lambda, we get

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) (0 + 1) [2,3]
```

substituting foldl again...

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((\acc x -> acc + x) (0+1) 2) [3]
```

and evaluating the accumulator:

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((0 + 1) + 2) [3]
```

and substituting foldl again...

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((\acc x -> acc + x) ((0 + 1) + 2) 3) []
```

again, evaluating the accumulator:

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) []
```

now we get to the second (terminating) case of foldl because we apply it to an empty list and are left with only:

```
(((0 + 1) + 2 ) + 3)
```

which we can of course evaluate to get `6`.

As you can see, there's no magic involved here: `x` is just a name you gave to a function argument. You could've named it `user8314628` instead and it would've worked the same way. What's binding the value of the head of the list to that argument isn't any pattern matching you do yourself, but what `foldl` actually does with the list.

Note that you can evaluate any haskell expression using this step-by-step process; You usually won't have to, but it's useful to do this a couple of times with functions that do more-or-less complicated things and you are unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1):

> how does the expression `acc + x` knows that `x` is the element in `xs`?

It doesn't. It computes a sum of whatever is passed to it.

Note that `(\acc x -> acc + x)` can be written simply as `(+)`.

Answer (score 0):

Folds take each consecutive values of the input list while making passing the remainder back to a function transparent. If you were to write your own `sum’` function, you would have to pass the remainder back to your function. You would also have to pass an **accumulator** back to your own function to keep a running total. Fold does not make explicit the processing of a list by taking the first value and passing the remainder. What it does explicate is the accumulator. It does also have to keep a running total in the case of a sum function. The accumulator is explicit because some recursive functions may do different things with it.